# Create multiple sharepoint items using JavaScript on new form but delay next page load until all created

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, callback

I am trying to create multiple sharepoint list items based on the new item form. This is for a recurring task list functionality. I have a lot of code that calculates dates etc based on the field inputs. The code runs when the user clicks 'save' on the form (triggers `PreSaveAction`)

The code looks something like this:

```
//load jquery

$(document).ready(function(){
    var siteUrl = //URL of list

    function PreSaveAction(siteUrl){
        //define j and FrequencyValue, and other code that calculates dates

        while(j < (FrequencyValue+1)){
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TestJava');
            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

            this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo); //add new item to the current list
            oListItem.set_item('Title', TitleValue + i);
            //oListItem.set_item all other relevant fields
            oListItem.update();
            clientContext.load(oListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }
    return true
}

function onQuerySucceeded() { 
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) { 
}
```

I may have messed up some of the { } or other code, but I think i have the key parts of the code here so it is understandable.

The issue I run into, is occasionally if the server goes slow, that not all items are created. For example, the code may be asked to create 12 items, but it only creates 11 (this is rare though). If I push the code to try and create 90 items just for a test, it may only create 40 of them. I have narrowed it down to the fact that the code is sent to the server to create the list items, but if the next page loads (the list view), then any items not created by that point are cut off and not created.

I need to modify the code so that I can guarantee 100% that all list items are created, as missing one off will have large consequences. I have been doing research, and thought that callbacks or promises might help, but I am new to JavaScript, so am not sure how to implement ( I have tried , but with no success).

I have used a sleep function to delay the end of the code, which does increase the chances of all items being created, but is not 100% guaranteed, and also is not ideal!

Let me know if I need to provide more details, as I said, the code is working, but not 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use Callback function to create multiple SharePoint items

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var siteUrl = //URL of list
j=0;
    function PreSaveAction(j){
        //define j and FrequencyValue, and other code that calculates dates

        if(j < (FrequencyValue+1)){
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TestJava');
            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

            this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo); //add new item to the current list
            oListItem.set_item('Title', TitleValue + i);
            //oListItem.set_item all other relevant fields
            oListItem.update();
            clientContext.load(oListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }else{
               return true;
        }

}

function onQuerySucceeded() { 
j=j+1;
PreSaveAction(j)
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) { 
alert("Something went wrong")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurring because the first query is succeeding and redirecting you to the next page, before all the async queries have been submitted. This is why it is more likely to occur on slower networks, or when there are more queries to submit.

The best solution (IMO) is to use `deferreds` and `promises` to make sure that all async queries get submitted and that all queries are completed before moving to the next page

```
//load jquery

$(document).ready(function(){
    var siteUrl = //URL of list

    function PreSaveAction(siteUrl){

        // Create a deferred object that contains all the async queries
        var buildDeferredSaves = $.Deferred(function(){

            // get ClientContext outside of while loop and reuse
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

            // get List object outside of while loop and reuse
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TestJava');
            var itemCreateInfo;

            while(j < (FrequencyValue+1)){
                itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

                this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo); //add new item to the current list
                oListItem.set_item('Title', TitleValue + i);
                //oListItem.set_item all other relevant fields
                oListItem.update();
                clientContext.load(oListItem);
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                    function() {
                        // Successful
                        buildDeferredSaves.resolve();
                    },
                    function(sender, args) {
                        // Failure
                        buildDeferredSaves.reject(args.get_message());
                    });
                );
            }

            // now that all async queries have been defined return the promise
            return buildDeferredSaves.promise();
        });

        var asyncPromises = buildDeferredSaves();   // execute the queries and return the promise

        asyncPromises.done(function(result) { 
            // Done means ALL async queries have been completed
            // can now redirect to next page
        });

        userPromise.fail(function(result) { 
            // Fail means ANY of the async queries failed
        });
    }
}
```